# How to open pdf from ajax response

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to open a PDF document received as a response text, in a new browser tab.

My controller code is :

```
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord,'HTML');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('helloWorld.html');
$data = $pdf->stream();
return $data;
```

And the ajax code so far (not working) :

```
$('body').on('click', '.printInvoice', function () {
    var purchase_id = $(this).data("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/purchases/print" + '/' + purchase_id,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var blob = data;
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = "PdfName-" + new Date().getTime() + ".pdf";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                var data2 = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                alert(data2['errors']);
            }
        });
});
```

The code above is generating the following error :
'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Please help to fix the above code, or give a better solution to the problem.

Comment: If you want the pdf file in a new tab just make a `window.open(thePdfLink, '_blank');`

Comment: The error needs to be fixed first.  I am getting error on this line "link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);"

Comment: No, what is the value  of data? a link?

Comment: data is pdf file binary. Starting like this "%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R >>
endobj"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this way, 
I have a better option for you!

Don't send information via ajax. use **window.location.href**

example code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.printInvoice', function () {
   var purchase_id = $(this).data("id");
   window.location.href = "/purchases/print" + '/' + purchase_id;
});
```

Don't forget to **die** at end of the route.

Comment: I am using Modal CRUD for form input.  Data is shown in Datatables with Edit,Delete,Print buttons with each row.  I want to print the invoice on click of this button. Button actions are handled in ajax.

Comment: Thanks, its working. But pdf opens in current window.  How can I open it in a new Tab.

Comment: Got it in new tab with "window.open('/purchases/print' + '/' + purchase_id,'_blank')"